# Notepad++ how to bulk add word to first line each txt file

Tags: notepad++

I have 100 txt files

I wanna add choosen word in first line of those files. 
All files have few words on first line, the best option will be if I can add this word in first line at random place for example: First word in line, after first word, after second word etc. But is not neccesary.

Comment: What is a "word" for you? Only alphabetics? Alphanumerics? Word character class `[A-Za-z0-9_]`? Alphanumerics with non latin characters? Everything that is not a space or punctuation? Something else?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61674480/edit) and add some examples of input lines and expected result.

Comment: word
What is a "word" for you? Only alphabetics? Alphanumerics? Word character class [A-Za-z0-9_]? Alphanumerics with non latin characters? Everything that is not a space or punctuation? Something else?

this is word for me, just normal word without numbers

Answer (score 0):

On Notepad++, the best option you have to do so is to perform a vertical selection and type in what you need.

Normally, you select words on a row-wise fashion (e.g. using your mouse). Pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> (or <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> if you are a keyaboard fan) you are able to select stuff in a column-wise fashion. Select the entire column 0 and start typing in your word. You'll be adding column of text in.

In case this is not suiting your needs (e.g. because of word alignment), you may try using other tools outside Notepad++, like `awk` or `cat`. Especially since you have that large amount of files, `awk` is probably the best alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

Search: ^\A(.*)$
Replace by: ANYTHING $1

but still like to know how to put the word randomly on first line like on this example:

First word in line, after first word, after second word etc.